Can there be "partial" confessions and "partial" absolutions in Catholic spiritual life?
Let's imagine a gay man which tries to be a good Catholic and who is trying to develop all the virtues except for 6th Commandment virtues that are related to his fate. And even then - he tries to adhere to the 6th Commandment as much as it possible, e.g. by committing to loving and monogamous relationships. We can also assume that he has read some theological articles which suggest discernment and care for his situation (there are some in the Catholic academic journal which I will not link here, because they can be offending and divisive for the general audience and which is just theology in the development, no surprises).
My question is - can this man go to the confession and acknoweldge all the sins and be ready to do penance for all of them, except that he is not giving promise not to sin again in the matters of 6th Commandment. Can priest give at least a partial absolution to his man and nurture at least all the other spheres of his spiritual growth?
Of course, partial absolution may be not much worth - i.e. - it still won't allow to participate in the Communion. But - from the other side - this can be step in the right direction and least partial holiness can be achieved. And the Salvator will take care of the remaining.
What can the attitudes of priest can be? Of course, this man will have long life in parish and he will go to the Confession each month and again and again the priest will have to listen that there is part that is not being corrected and improved stubbornly and the absolution can not be given again. But still - maybe that is possible?

to his fate? What does that mean?

Assuming that the excepted sins were mortal, then the confession wouldn't be valid. Even if the priest didn't know about the exception and gave absolution, the confession still wouldn't be valid.

Andreas is correct. A penitent who withholds confessing even one mortal sin intentionally invalidates the Sacrament.

No, I am not talking about witholding. The man under consideration is ready to confess 6th commandment matter as well and do penance for it (as much as is possible), bet he cannot make sincere promise no to do this sin again. So, everything OK, except fot no giving promise and for not having sense of despair, because that is the fate.

Then he is not contrite. He has no intention of attempting to stop. So he is not repentant, he is just open about it. "Hey, I'm secretly part of a cult that is trying to communicate with the dead. I know it is wrong, I'll do penance, but I'm not going to stop the witchcraft".

@TomR sincere promise doesn't mean you will not, but that you will strive not to. He may claim to be (or you may claim for him) that his actions avoid a "sense of despair" but in real spiritual terms, he is despairing because he is effectively denying the possibility of God's grace to prevent him those sins.


The Catechism of the Council of Trent explains:
“There is nothing that should be better known to the faithful than the matter of this Sacrament; hence they should be taught that Penance differs from the other Sacraments in this that while the matter of the other Sacraments is something, whether natural or artificial, the matter, as it were, of the Sacrament of Penance is the acts of the penitent – namely, contrition, confession and satisfaction – as has been declared by the Council of Trent.”


To my understanding of catholic confession, you have to actually intent to repent. And while you might not be condemned in that legalistic system for being human and forgetting something... you are describing the ongoing act of a "mortal sin", without contrition, with no intention of stopping, and no remorse of any kind... then the act of "confession" is invalid.
I checked on a Catholic apologetics site and they claim you need the following.

Contrition (real sorrow for the sin)
The desire to change your life away from the sin.
The actual confession of the sin, without hiding details.
The intent to perform penance.

Your description suggests that 1, 2, and 4 would not occur.

I think the point you need to emphasize would be that contrition etc must be total; that is, you can't be contrite for some of your sins and be absolved.

@esques In the example of a sinner who is not intending to attempt to not sin. The issue is not that contrition must be total, the issue is that there is no intent to stop committing the sin.  Be it adultery, witchcraft, or perhaps just a little bit of hobby axe murdering. Without the intent to stop there is no forgiveness, because your actions are what will judge you when the book of life is read.

Are you saying you can be contrite but still intend to commit the sin? If not, you are making a distinction without a difference. The requirement per se is contrition which may be imperfect, but must be total.

@eques NO. That is literally not what I wrote. I said if you go and confess that you have been committing a mortal sin, but you have no intent to stop. Then you have NOT been contrite. You would NOT have been repentant. If you are NOT repentant you are NOT forgiven.

So you do agree with me then that contrition must be total?

I believe you agree with me. The "contrition" is incomplete if there is no intent to stop sinning, because you would not have any "real sorrow" about the sin. Which based on the research and understanding I have... is necessary for the sacrament in the catholic tradition.
